# Is there any reason to prefer a T3i if a T4i has the same price?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, canon-600d, canon-650d

I've found an offer for T4i or T3i at the same price. Is there any strong reason I should stick with T3i and not upgrade to T4i? I'm asking this because of the obvious success of T3i, which is sort-of intimidating me to go for the upgrade.

Comment: I would suggest to get the T4i - just make sure you buy from a reputed distributor, and be cautious about those mail-in-rebates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should almost certainly go for the T4i if the price is the same or similar. The T4i has better technical specs and features, including video auto focus,  cross-type focus points and faster continuous shooting. The T4i is also thinner than the T3i.

[Snapsort](http://snapsort.com/compare/Canon-Rebel-T4i-vs-Canon-T3i) provides good analysis of cameras from their specs and also compares cameras face to face, contrasting their good and bad points.

Comment: The T4i also has a touchscreen interface, which is apparently really nice to have.